# How do I use Navigation.pop to go to the previous screen on iOS?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-navigation

I have `ScreenA`, from which I'm pushing `ScreenB` like this:

```
Navigation.push(this.props.componentId, {
        component: {
            name: "ScreenB"
        },
    },
);
```

At `ScreenB`, I have a custom back button, which `onPress` does this:

`Navigation.pop(this.props.componentId);`

This works perfectly well on Android (I am able to navigate back and forth between `ScreenA` and `ScreenB`). On iOS though, after clicking the back button, it goes to `ScreenA` but instantly comes back to `ScreenB`. This happens only the first time. After it takes me back to `ScreenB`, if I click the back button again, it behaves as it should, and I land at `ScreenA`.

I am using `react-native-navigation`, not `react-navigation`.

At `ScreenA`, I have a reset button in the navigation bar that is configured like this:

```
public componentDidMount() {
    this.navigationEventListener = Navigation.events().bindComponent(this);
}

public navigationButtonPressed = (event: NavigationButtonPressedEvent) => {
    if (event.buttonId === "resetButton") {
        this.props.reset();
    }
}

public componentDidUnMount() {
    if (this.navigationEventListener) {
        this.navigationEventListener.remove();
    }
}
```

Any idea what could be a good way to debug/solve this is appreciated.

Comment: Could you add more code from your component? Do you implement any hook, like componentDidMount?

Comment: @diogenesgg I edited the question with some more code from `ScreenA`. `ScreenB` doesn't have anything like that, just the `render` function.